# for command variable unexpected at this time

Tags: variables, for-loop, batch-file, command

```
dxdiag /t output.txt
FOR %%GeForce IN output.txt DO echo You have an NVIDIA GPU.
FOR %%Radeon IN output.txt DO echo You have an AMD GPU.
```

The above is a snippet of a batch file I created. When I run it, the error message below appears:

```
%GeForce was unexpected at this time.
```

And the batch file quits. I've tried other answers already, but none seem to help. Is anything wrong with my syntax? I'm running Windows XP SP3 on a Dell Latitude E6400.

Answer (score 1):

That is not valid syntax for FOR
What you want for this is

```
find "GeForce" output2.txt >nul && echo You have an NVIDIA GPU.
find "Radeon" output2.txt >nul && echo You have an AMD GPU.
```

Answer (score -1):

Herro, if you want to try doing this with the "for" command try this

```
dxdiag /t output.txt
FOR /f %%a IN (output.txt) DO (
if %%a == GeForce echo You have an NVIDIA GPU.)
FOR /f %%a IN (output.txt) DO (
if %%a == Radeon echo You have an AMD GPU.)
```

This looks at everyline in your text file and if it finds a line that has "Geforce"or "Radeon" it will echo the following message.

*Note it is only for an entire line of text.

Yours, Mona

Comment: It will not process an entire line of text without the "delims=" section.

Comment: Try it with spaces in the lines in output.txt.  You are assuming the first token in a line is the one of interest.